# Strange behaviour of Perl's push function

Tags: arrays, perl

I am writing a dedicated ICS (iCalendar file) parser.

I pass an array to a subroutine. All variables are single values apart from `$notdates` which is a comma-separated list of dates.

```
@entryl = ($dtstart, $dtend, $attendee, $lastmod, $uid, $notdates);
&entrytoarray(@entryl);

sub entrytoarray {

  # print Dumper @_;
  my $shiftdur = (&stamptoepoc($_[1]) - &stamptoepoc($_[0])) / 60 / 60;
  my $attendee = $_[2];
  my $deleted  = $_[5];
  $attendee =~ /ATTENDEE;USER-KEY=([^;]*);CN=([^;]*);.*:(.*)/;

  my %ehash = (
    "STARTDATE"   , &stamptodate($_[0]),
    "ENDDATE"     , &stamptodate($_[1]),
    "STARTSTAMP"  , $_[0],
    "ENDSTAMP"    , $_[1],
    "USERKEY"     , $1,
    "CN"          , $2,
    "EMAIL"       , $3,
    "LASTMOD"     , $_[3],
    "UID"         , $_[4],
    "DURATION"    , $shiftdur
  );

  # Only keep current data
  my $fdays = 4;
  my $tdays = 7;

  chomp(my $curstamp = `TZ="UTC" date -d "$fdays days" +"%Y%m%d%H%M00"`);
  chomp(my $stpstamp = `TZ="UTC" date -d "$tdays days" +"%Y%m%d%H%M00"`);

  if (($_[0] > $curstamp) && ($_[1] < $stpstamp)) {

    if (defined($deleted)) {

      my @deleted = split /,/, $deleted;

      foreach (@deleted) {
        if ($_ ne $_[0]) {
          push(@entry, \%ehash);
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      push(@entry, \%ehash);
    }
  }

  print Dumper @entry;
```

This works mostly as expected:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'DURATION' => '5',
          'STARTSTAMP' => '20141122230000',
          'UID' => '20141114T010539Z--1092363482',
          'LASTMOD' => '20141118214419',
          'STARTDATE' => '2014-11-22 23:00:00',
          'EMAIL' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          'ENDDATE' => '2014-11-23 04:00:00',
          'CN' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
          'ENDSTAMP' => '20141123040000',
          'KEY' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'EMAIL' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          'ENDDATE' => '2014-11-23 23:00:00',
          'ENDSTAMP' => '20141123230000',
          'KEY' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
          'CN' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          'STARTDATE' => '2014-11-23 19:00:00',
          'LASTMOD' => '20141118205901',
          'UID' => '20141114T010456Z--1092363482',
          'DURATION' => '4',
          'STARTSTAMP' => '20141123190000'
        };
$VAR3 = $VAR2;
```

Where is the $VAR3 = $VAR2 coming from?

Comment: Do not pass arrays directly to Dumper. You should be doing `print Dumper \@entry;` (passing a reference).

Comment: add more code so it's a complete runnable example (where is @entry  coming from?)

Comment: Also, it may not be wrong but using `$_` and `@_` in the same expression (`if ($_ ne $_[0]) {`) is, at best, very confusing.

Comment: @ysth: `$deleted` is there. It's `$_[5]`

Comment: I would guess that `$_ ne $_[0]` is true twice for some values, which leads to two copies of `%eHash` being pushed onto the array. Since its the same array, Data::Dumper uses a reference instead of duplicating the data.

Comment: Just use [Text::vFile::asData](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/Text-vFile-asData/lib/Text/vFile/asData.pm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this section is the culprit:

```
  foreach (@deleted) {
    if ($_ ne $_[0]) {
      push(@entry, \%ehash);
    }
  }
```

If you have several values in the array, the if-statement can be true twice, and thus push a value twice. Unless this is wanted behaviour, I would make sure that only one value is pushed. You can do this by using `grep` instead:

```
if (grep { $_ ne $_[0] } @deleted) {
    push @entry, \%ehash;
}
```

Note that this replaces the `foreach` loop.

Comment: As far as we can see, `@entry` should contain only references to `%ehash` so they should *all* be the same. Invisible code must be creating the first element in a different way.

Comment: @Borodin: yes, looks like two calls to the subroutine, one of which does two pushes

Comment: I agree, there is more than one shifty thing about this code. Presumably there are 3 different calls to the sub, but only one is shown in the code.

Comment: But the `print Dumper` is *inside* the subroutine, so there would also have been multiple dumps, which he didn't mention.

Comment: Thanks TLP, that sorted it. And you are correct in your presumption of it being called by different calls. A call is made to the sub for a single entry and for daily repeated entries.

Comment: @Borodin, my bad, I placed that in the script as lead-in for the result, the actual Dumper is not in the subroutine, I should have be more vigilant on that - apologies for the confusion!

Comment: @user3513601: That's largely a result of your poor indentation that I had to fix before I could read your code. It's generally a bad idea to put the open and close braces `{...}` on the same line, and one-space indenting isn't enough. Two to four is the usual choice.

Comment: Good to know - thanks! Still coming to grips with Perl, but loving it  :)

Comment: @Werner: Take a look at [perlstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) for an excellent set of coding style guidelines. The majority of the best Perl programmers use something very similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your array `@entry` contains hash references. `Data::Dumper` is saying that the first and second elements of the array refer to two different hashes, while the third refers to the same hash as the second.

You don't show where `@entry` comes from, but I would expect *all three* elements to be references to `%ehash`.

The problem is that, if you keep pushing a reference to `%ehash` onto `@entry`, they all point to the same data item, and the intermediate states of the hash won't be recorded.

Unless you mean `entrytoarray` to push only *one* copy of `%ehash` (in which case there's a separate problem that we can't see) you need to fix it by either writing

```
push @entry, { %ehash }
```

which copies the hash and returns a reference to the copy, or you can declare and populate `%ehash` *inside* the `foreach` loop, which will create a new hash each time around the loop.